# ranking one column grouped by another column

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to add a calculated column which sums up per account no. Then I am trying to rank these as per account group separately.

First I tried to create the Total per Account column as

```
sub_total = 
sumx(filter(all('Mizan Full'),'Mizan Full'[Account No] = EARLIER('Mizan Full'[Account No])),'Mizan Full'[Total])
```

this one is ok but :

then how can i give the ranks column as grouped by another column ?

```
rankx(allselected('Mizan Full'),'Mizan Full'[sub_total],,0)
```

or

```
RANKX(filter(('Mizan Full'), 'Mizan Full'[Account Group]= EARLIER('Mizan Full'[Account Group])), 'Mizan Full'[sub_total],,,Dense)
```

what am i doing wrong ?

| Account Group | Account No | Total | sub_total | Rank per Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 120.01.C8716 | -15.924,00 | 2.890.730,00 | 1 |
| 120 | 120.01.C8716 | 2.906.654,00 | 2.890.730,00 | 1 |
| 120 | 120.01.C8717 | -290.733,00 | -274.809,00 | 2 |
| 120 | 120.01.C8717 | 15.924,00 | -274.809,00 | 2 |
| 159 | 159.01.003 | 108.475,00 | 108.475,00 | 1 |
| 335 | 335.01.C16805 | 3.238.202,00 | 3.238.202,00 | 1 |
| 335 | 335.01.C16808 | 2.154.455,00 | 2.154.455,00 | 2 |
| 335 | 335.01.C16807 | 290.733,00 | 290.733,00 | 3 |
| 335 | 335.01.C16806 | 2.154.455,00 | - | 4 |
| 335 | 335.01.C16806 | -2.154.455,00 | - | 4 |
| 335 | 335.01.C15052 | -1.500,00 | -1.500,00 | 5 |
| 335 | 335.01.C16809 | -70.911,00 | -70.911,00 | 6 |
| 335 | 335.01.C16810 | -70.911,00 | -70.911,00 | 6 |
| 335 | 335.01.C16811 | -89.000,00 | -89.000,00 | 7 |
| 393 | 393.02.002 | -70.911,00 | -70.911,00 | 1 |
| 393 | 393.02.001 | -70.911,00 | -191.284,00 | 2 |
| 393 | 393.02.001 | -70.911,00 | -191.284,00 | 2 |
| 393 | 393.02.001 | -70.911,00 | -191.284,00 | 2 |
| 393 | 393.02.001 | 15.924,00 | -191.284,00 | 2 |
| 393 | 393.02.001 | 5.525,00 | -191.284,00 | 2 |

Edit :

I am attaching the sample file. I think I am almost there but I dont understand why

1. under group 335 - zero value must get rank 4 but it gets rank 8 and rank 4 is missing
2. under group 120 - listed as rank 2 and rank 4 but it should be 1 & 2
3. under group 393 - listed as rank 1 and rank 10 ???

[Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12EgFfhwLUfHK2m2P3I5Re6zyTaN1Z4Zd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Mik ? are you there ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a new table and measure but i am sure there is a better way...

Table :

```
MeasureTablo =
 SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
'Table'[Account Group ],
'Table'[Account No ],
"Toplam", SUM ( 'Table'[Total ] )
```

Measure :

```
Sira No =
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( MeasureTablo ),
        MeasureTablo[Account Group ] = EARLIER ( MeasureTablo[Account Group ] )
    ),
    ( MeasureTablo[Toplam] ),
    ,
    ,
    DENSE
)
```